# Breaking image pixels when a scalar is added to image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I wanted to adjust an image's brightness, by adding a scalar

I wrote this code.

```py
img1 = np.uint8(np.clip(img + 45, 0, 255))
img2 = np.uint8(np.clip(img + 45., 0, 255))

plt.imshow(img1) 
plt.show()
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.show()
```

Only difference between `img1` and `img2` is type of the adding value.

`img1` is added **an integer**, `img2` is added **a float**.

But the results are different.

You can see the results in the link below

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/vd6talup5nre312/pixel_diff.png?raw=1

I don't understand why the pixels are broken when an **integer added**. 
even I clipped the values with `np.clip`

Can someone please tell me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You overflow the allowed range.

»But I'm using `np.clip()` and cast it to `uint8`!« you want to say.

Right, but too late.  Your `img` is probably already of type `uint8`, and as long as you add an integer to an integer, the type is not changed, so the first addition `img + 45` adds `45` in the range of a `uint8`, and there already your overflow takes place (e. g. `231 + 45 → 276 → 20`).  The `np.clip()` later will not change a thing (because `20` already is within the range).

You can actually do it correctly by a variety of ways.  One you found, by adding a float value.  This will automatically upcast the `uint8` to a float value *prior* to executing the addition.  Then the rest takes place as intended (clipping, downcasting).

You can also do the addition in the `uint8` range, then check the value for having an overflow (<45?) and set all these values to max (`255`).  But I guess this is unnecessarily complex, unless you have, for instance, memory issues (if you cannot hold the image in memory as floats).  In normal cases, this is probably no problem.

You could also use `np.clip(img, 0, 255-45) + 45` to avoid the overflow in the first place.  But I think this also isn't easy to understand for the next maintainer, so in a professional environment, this doesn't beat the use of a float and downcast as in your second approach.